# enum/integral casting from throw/catch?

Tags: c++, exception, implicit-conversion

As I understand it, the exception system in C++ doesn't implicitly cast to/from types that can be cast without issue, and I'd assume this is for more strict debugging; if you're throwing a `bool`, you may not want it to be caught in a statement where `int` is the exception type. This makes it particularly tricky for me to do the following:

```
enum Exception {
  Flag1 = 1,  //  0b00000001
  Flag2 = 2,  //  0b00000010
  Flag3 = 4,  //  0b00000100
  Flag4 = 8   //  0b00001000
  // And so on...
};

void doSomeStuff() {
  // Theoretical code happens here
  throw Flag1;
}

int main() {
  try {
    doSomeStuff();
  } catch (Exception exception) {
    if (exception & Flag1) {
      std::cout << "Flag 1 is fatal" << std::endl;
      return exception;
    }
    if (exception & Flag2) std::cout << "Flag 2 is non-fatal" << std::endl;
    if (exception & Flag3) std::cout << "Flag 3 is non-fatal" << std::endl;
    if (exception & Flag4) {
      std::cout << "Flag 4 is fatal" << std::endl;
      return exception;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It all works just fine when I'm only using 1 flag at a time, but once I throw anything that's been OR'd (e.g. `throw Flag1 | Flag2;`), it no longer "fits inside" the enum and terminates.

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'`

The fix for this is seemingly simple -- change `catch (Exception exception)` to `catch (int exception)`, because enum values are always convertible to integrals, but not the other way around. However, when I throw an enum value on its own, I now get the same error but in reverse.

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Exception'`

I can think of 3 possible fixes:

- Explicitly cast to int every time I throw (the code that I'm actually trying to do this with is a very generic callback; could be run for dozens of different functions. Gross!)
- Have duplicate `catch(){}` statements (because I am only sometimes returning from `main()` depending on the flags of the value thrown, I can't put this into its own function; even more gross)
- Instead of an `enum`, use constants; probably just as fast (they both compile to literals), but less organized and should be completely unnecessary.

Are these my only options, or am I missing something?

Comment: Rather use some technique like the `std::iobase` does in combination with the stream-state flags, an exception masks.

Comment: [`enum class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) Which, on second read, may not be as useful here as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think that `Flag1 | Flag2` is considered by compiler as an `int` and not as a `Exception`

try casting the `or`ed values before throwing

```
throw (int)(Flag1 | Flag2);
```

Comment: I did list that as an option in the original question; I'm not keen on doing that because it means I have to for every single throw. In the environment I'm actually trying to do this, I'm using std::function class members as callbacks, meaning that this would have to be a thing in more than just 1 function like I show in the example.